# Flatness of R[X]/I over R

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, galois-representations

In the famous paper *Simple flat extensions*, Journal of Algebra Volume **16**, Issue 1, September 1970, p. 105-107, Wolmer V. Vasconcelos proves the following

> **Theorem (Vasconcelos).** For a noetherian ring $R$, let $S \colon= R[X]/I$. Then $S$ is flat over $R$ if and only if $I$ is a projective module of $R[X]$ and the content $c(I)$, which is the ideal generated all coefficients of polynomials contained in $I$, of $I$ is generated by an idempotent element of $R$.

At the concluding remark at page 106, Vasconcelos suggested the possible generalisation of this theorem to the non-noetherian ring $R$ where a finitely generated flat module is projective.

> **Question.** Does this result still hold if $R$ is replaced with a non-noetherian coherent local ring?

By using Bourbaki $R$ being coherent ensures the assumption in the remark by Vasconcelos, so the question should be interesting.

Comment: The theorem you've stated is clearly false and isn't what Vasconcelos proves (article is here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869370900438). For a counterexample to your statement take R = Z, I = 2 R[X].

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler In your example, the content ideal is generated by 2, not an idempotent. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mohan Yes: you're missing the timestamps on my comment and the OP's edit. (My comment related to an earlier version of the question which omitted the hypothesis about the content ideal.)